# How to get result from void pointer pointer in C# P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I'm trying to write a C# wrapper around the Windows candlelight library and I've gotten stuck on this function:

```
typedef void* candle_list_handle;

DLL bool __stdcall candle_list_scan(candle_list_handle *list);
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
        [DllImport("candle_api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool candle_list_scan(ref IntPtr listPtr);

        public candle_list_t? Scan()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
            var res = candle_list_scan(ref ptr);

            var list = Marshal.PtrToStructure<candle_list_t>(ptr);


            if (res)
            {
                return list;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

I also tried:

```
        [DllImport("candle_api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool candle_list_scan(ref IntPtr listPtr);

        public candle_list_t? Scan()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
            var res = candle_list_scan(ref ptr);

            var list = Marshal.PtrToStructure<candle_list_t>(ptr);

            if (res)
            {
                return list;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

But neither have worked properly. Here is the C code where it sets the list:

```
bool __stdcall candle_list_scan(candle_list_handle *list)
{
    if (list==NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    candle_list_t *l = (candle_list_t *)calloc(1, sizeof(candle_list_t));
    *list = l;
    if (l==NULL) {
        return false;
    }
....
```

and candle_list_t is:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t num_devices;
    candle_err_t last_error;
    candle_device_t dev[CANDLE_MAX_DEVICES];
} candle_list_t;
```

which I converted to

```
    public struct candle_list_t
    {
        public byte num_devices;
        public candle_err_t last_error;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public candle_device_t[] dev;
    }
```

Using my first method, the num_devices value has a value but it is invalid as it is over the limit of what num_devices can be per the code in the C library. Using the second method, I just get an empty struct.

Comment: What I've done in the past is, if you can find a WINAPI function with a similar signature, https://pinvoke.net/ will give you the approximate code.  Big *if* maybe, but it's worked for me so far.  In your case, I don't think the `ref` keyword is warranted.

Comment: I find that `ref` looking a little out of place too. It shoud probably be an `IntPtr*` . But I'm no interop expert.

Comment: Since C allocates, just declare as `out IntPtr listPtr` not ref. Then Marshal.PtrToStructure on the returned pointer. Don't forget to add StructLayout Sequential to the struct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.8 also since C doesn't use a .NET-compatible allocator, you must provide to .NET side a free DLL export as well for the allocated structure.